# Java Simple JFrame will not show title

Tags: java, swing

I have a very simple JFrame, this is even an example and no matter what I try, I cannot get the JFrame to show a title.

```
public class Builder{
    public static void main(String s[]) {  
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();  
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
        JLabel label = new JLabel("JFrame By Example");  
        JButton button = new JButton();  
        button.setText("Button");  
        panel.add(label);  
        panel.add(button);  
        frame.add(panel);  
        frame.setSize(200, 300);  
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }  
}
```

The example shows the label and the button in the contents but not the title of the JFrame.

I am using the java-8-oracle JRE

Any help would be appreciated.

**Problem resolved itself.**
Thanks Everyone for assisting on this.

I can't really explain it.  I have written hundreds of apps to date and this has never occurred.  Even the old apps didn't show the title.

I rebooted the machine after closing down eclipse.  After I restarted eclipse it just started working correctly.  No updates were pending that needed the machine restarted.  I do think the machine restart fixed it,  not sure why.

Comment: What OS? I'm not sure if every os shows a title by default.

Comment: @matt and if that the case you might try `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());`

Comment: I made the change to call UIManager.setLook... with the same result.  I am on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS

Comment: Which look and feel did you use, there are a couple of them?

Comment: Do other apps have a title? Does unity display the title in the top bar when an app is selected?

Comment: I'm not sure what unity is, but Eclipse does.

Comment: Unity is the default desktop environment for ubuntu 16.04. Also, you skipped my question about which look and feel you used. Anyways, I added an answer with a way to look for more look and feels and how to request look and feel related decorations. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your JFrame isn't wide enough, so the title is being cut off by the minimize, maximize, and close buttons.

Instead of `frame.setSize(200, 300);`, try:

```
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
```

And now you should see your title. Also, don't forget `frame.pack();` before `frame.setVisible(true);`.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Builder {
    public static void main(String s[]) {  
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();  

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
        JLabel label = new JLabel("JFrame By Example");  

        JButton button = new JButton();  
        button.setText("Button");  

        panel.add(label);  
        panel.add(button);  

        frame.add(panel);  
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }  
}
```

[image: JFrame example with Title]

Comment: Also worth noting that you should run your swing GUI from the EDT.

Comment: Nope, similar result.  This is just an example that I found to try to explain why I can't get the title on the frame.  I normally use SwingUtilities to launch the application.  I have struggled with this for two days now.  Could something be wrong with JRE?  I am running this from Eclipse.

Comment: @Nefarious this is a rare case where you might consider adding a screenshot of your issue - since I saw the title when running the above

Comment: The title bar is part of the window decorations, it would be quite unexpected if setSize cropped off a titlebar.

Comment: @matt when running the OP's code on windows, there was no title (it was cut off), however after making the frame wider I saw the title of the frame ‾\_(ツ)_/‾

Comment: Here ya go, \. Also, I was just thinking of it being horizontally cutoff, but you're right if the app isn't wide enough you couldn't see the whole title.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that might help, the look and feel, and the window decorations.

```
for( UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo lfi:  UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()){
        System.out.println(lfi);
}
```

That would show you all of the available look and feels. I am pretty sure metal will show you a title.

The next thing is to request the decorations from the look and feel.

```
frame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

Since I don't have a non-title issue it is hard for me to verify, but I suspect this should get you a titlebar.

Comment: I called UIManager.getLookAndFeel() and it is MetalLookAndFeel.

Comment: when I call frame.setUndecorated(true) all of the top bar goes away, no close, minimize,.... when I change it to false, I get the close, minimize,... but no title.

Comment: @Nefarious I didn't suggest 'setUndecorated' I suggested setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated, which the documentation says the title would be handled by the look and feel. Also, the setUndecorated behavior you describe is exactly what I'd expect to happen.

Comment: I did both, the first didn't work either.  I am using Eclipse Oxygen.  I think I am going to reload eclipse, maybe it has a jre library mix up or something.  I'm just grasping at straws now.

Comment: @Nefarious I really doubt it has something to do with eclipse, or the jre you're using. I suspect it is unity. Try the different look and feel's too, maybe metal doesn't have a title bar, but the code I posted will give you a list of all of the look and feels.

Comment: @Nefarious Thinking about it some more you example is so simple, you should be able to try it w/out eclipse at all. Just incase it is using a stale version of your program somewhere.